# Maven 3 - Unable to find archetype

Tags: maven, archetypes

I have created a customized archetype, customA-web-archetype. Within the project folder, customA-web-archetype , I ran `mvn clean install archetype:update-local-catalog` which was successful. Now when I run `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local` outside the folder to use the archetype, I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)

Choose archetype:


Your filter doesn't match any archetype (hint: enter to return to initial list)
```

FYI- When I was setting up Maven, I moved the .m2 to a different directory rather than using the default home directory.  I made the appropriate change to settings.xml so that it can find the .m2 in the updated directory structure.

I am not using any repo manager such as Nexus. Just a local m2 repo sitting on the same box as the archetype project.

Answer (score 3):

To run the archetype command, you need to specify the groupId, artefactId and version of your archetype, as well as those of your future maven project.

You should try the following command, with your own parameters:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local -DarchetypeGroupId=yourArchetypeGroupId -DarchetypeArtifactId=yourArchetypeArtifactId -DarchetypeVersion=yourArchetypeVersion -DgroupId=projectGroupId -DartifactId=projectArtifactId -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: " mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local " should list locally created archetype and I should be able to pick one.  It could not find anything local although it is in the local repo.  It will only list remote archetype. Do you know why?

Comment: I agree that I had the problem too. A workaround could be to define your archetype inside your archetype-catalog.xml file under .m2 repository (or your own local maven repository), but I'm not sure it is very pretty.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and the archetype I'm looking for is in the archetype-catalog.xml file.  Also, mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file://home/ses44/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml doesn't work

Comment: god bless you, finally an answer to my problem!

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading from Maven 2 to 3 we found the same problem.  The fix was to change the version of the archetype-packaging and maven-archetype-plugin from 2.2 to 3.0.0 in the archetype pom.

I looks like maven moved the location of it's archetype repository file from ~/.m2 to ~/.m2/repositories which is why generate wasn't finding it.

One strange behavior I'm still seeing is that if I just do

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

it doesn't show my local archetypes, however if I do a

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

it shows up.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried crawling the repo to create a catalog? Perhaps it's missing / broken? Archetype plugin has crawl goal, which parses the repo and creates catalog.xml.

```
mvn archetype:help
[... snip ...]
archetype:crawl
  Crawl a Maven repository (filesystem, not HTTP) and creates a catalog file.
```